# Why do people say "吃飽了嗎"

Tags: meaning, usage, expressions

I have heard my Chinese-speaking friends asking each other `吃飽了嗎？` several times when they are done or almost done with their own meal. And I have wondered, "Why would they ask others such question? Would it not imply that they are rushing others to eat faster?" I feel that the question indicates impatience and can be rather offensive, especially to those with a slower pace. Nonetheless, I tend to believe that the question has other implications. As such, is it really intended to rush others to eat faster?

Comment: If the one who asks the question is the one who will pay the bill, the situation would be a common phatic conversation -- the question `吃飽了嗎`  would imply, "if you feel the food is not enough, I will order more for you."

Comment: so they can stuff you more. just kidding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When asking a Chinese person "are you full" when eating a meal its like asking "are you enjoying your meal?" The host will be happy if he knows you are full.

But when someone says 你吃飽了嗎？ to you when not eating a meal. it means "Are you stupid?" or "Are you crazy?"

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! The second part is quite surprising to me...

Comment: @ThomasHsieh In the second situation, it's actually short for 你吃饱了撑的？

Comment: @xzczd Ah I've heard of that I think. Thanks much!

Answer (score 5):

It has more of an 'are you satisfied?' feel.

Answer (score 2):

It is nothing more than a sympathetic gesture. The more general 吃饭了没有？ just means ”how ya doing?”, ”are you alright?”.

Answer (score 1):

It simply implies kind of a care to you.If you say you're already full,that means you enjoy this meal and want no more.Sometimes,when you say you are full,it implies that you can do other things concentratedly.